# angularJS sending data from modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm curently workin on some project with angularJS and I'm stuck on this problem.I can't send data from modal to my scope because my data is undefined.

So if someone can help me I would appreciate it.
I'm very sorry if my English is little rusty.

Here is what I currently have.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery.js"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>


    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="siteCtrl">  
                    <!-- dodaj ng-controller="siteCtrl" -->
    <input type="button"  class="goToTop" value="Scroll Top" />


            <form class="navbar-form justify" role="search" ng-hide="hideSearch">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
                </div>
            </form>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="btnDiv">
            <input id="btnSites" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" name="addSite" value="Add Website" ng-click="toggleSites()">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" name="addGroup" value="Add Group" ng-click="toggleGroups()">
        </div>

        <div class="sites-info" >
                <button id="btnSites" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  ng-model="sites" ng-click="groupedWebsites()"> Websites 
                    <span class="badge">{{ ::promise.sites.length }}</span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-model="groups" ng-click="showGroups()"> Groups
                    <span class="badge">{{ ::promise.groups.length }}</span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-model="ungrouped"> Ungrouped Websites 
                    <span class="badge">{{ ungrouped}}</span>
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--  Placeholder for view-->
    <!--<div ng-view="">-->

    <modal title="Add Website" visible="showModal">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Site Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Site name"
                data-ng-model="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url">Site URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Site URL"
                data-ng-model="url">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color">Site color</label>
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color" data-ng-model="color">
                    <option selected >Choose color</option>
                    <option>Green</option>
                    <option>Red</option>
                    <option>Blue</option>
                    <option>Yellow</option>
                    <option>Orange</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="sites" class="form-inline">
                <label for="group">Choose group</label>
                <div ng-repeat="g in promise.groups">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="g.Checked" >
                    <span style="color:{{g.color}};">{{ g.name }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSite()">Add site</button>
        </form>
    </modal>



    <modal title="Add Groups" visible="showModal2">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url">Group name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="group_name" placeholder="Group name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color">Group color</label>
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="group_color" placeholder="Choose color">
                    <option>Choose color</option>
                    <option>Green</option>
                    <option>Red</option>
                    <option>Blue</option>
                    <option>Brown</option>
                    <option>Orange</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </modal>

    <modal title="Edit Site" visible="showModal3">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url">Site</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="site_url" placeholder="Site URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color">Site color</label>
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="site_color" placeholder="Choose color">
                    <option>Choose color</option>
                    <option>Green</option>
                    <option>Red</option>
                    <option>Blue</option>
                    <option>Yellow</option>
                    <option>Orange</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label for="group">Choose group</label>
                <div ng-repeat="g in promise.groups">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="g.Checked" >
                    <span style="color:{{g.color}};">{{ g.name }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </modal>



    <div class="container2">
        <table  id="allSites" class="table table-hover" ng-hide="hideTable1">
          <tr>
            <th>Site URL</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>

          <tr ng-repeat="site in promise.sites | searchFor:searchString"  >
            <td>
                <a href="http://{{site.url}}" style="color:{{site.color}}; text-decoration:none">{{ ::site.siteName }} </a>

            <td>
            <div class = "btn-group">

                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary"> Groups 
                <span class="badge">{{ ::site.group.length }}</span>
                </button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                        <span class = "caret"></span>
                        <span class = "sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>

                <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu" >
                    <li ng-repeat="g in site.group"><span>{{::g}}</span><hr></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleEditSites()">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <img src="images/glyphicons-208-remove.png" ng-click="deleteSites($index)"/>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table> 

        <div class="close-table">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-hide="hideButton1" ng-click="closeSites()">
            Close &times;
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>









    <div class="container2">
        <table class="table table-hover" ng-hide="hideTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Group name</th>
            <th>Sites</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>

          <tr ng-repeat="groups in promise.groups">
            <td style="color:{{groups.color}};">{{ ::groups.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class = "btn-group">

                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary"> Sites 
                        <span class="badge">{{ ::groups.sites.length }}</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                        <span class = "caret"></span>
                        <span class = "sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>

                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu" >
                        <li ng-repeat="s in groups.sites"><span>{{::s}}</span><hr></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleEditGroups()">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <img src="images/glyphicons-208-remove.png" ng-click="deleteGroup($index)"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table> 

        <div class="close-table">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-hide="hideButton" ng-click="closeGroups()">
            Close &times;
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>









<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/app/application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/controllers/siteCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts//animation/animation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/filters/searchFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modals/modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Next is application.js

```
var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

Contrlollers

siteCtrl.js

```
app.controller('siteCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    var promise= {};

    $http.get('JSON/data.json').then(function(res) {
        $scope.promise = res.data;
    console.log($scope.promise.sites);

    }, function() { promise = 'error'; });


    $scope.hideSearch=true;
    $scope.hideTable1=true;
    $scope.hideButton1=true;
    $scope.hideTable=true;
    $scope.hideButton=true;
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.showModal2 = false;


    $scope.groupedWebsites= function(){
        $scope.hideTable=true;
        $scope.hideButton=true;
        $scope.hideTable1=false;
        $scope.hideButton1=false;
        $scope.hideSearch=false;
    };
    $scope.closeSites=function(){
        $scope.hideTable1=true;
        $scope.hideButton1=true;
        $scope.hideSearch=true;
        $scope.searchString="";
    }
    $scope.showGroups= function(){
        $scope.hideTable1=true;
        $scope.hideButton1=true;
        $scope.hideTable=false;
        $scope.hideButton=false;
        $scope.hideSearch=true;
    };
    $scope.closeGroups=function(){
        $scope.hideTable=true;
        $scope.hideButton=true;
        $scope.searchString="";
    }
    $scope.toggleSites = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
    $scope.toggleGroups = function(){
        $scope.showModal2 = !$scope.showModal2;
    };
    $scope.toggleEditSites=function(){
        $scope.showModal3 = !$scope.showModal3;
    }

    $scope.deleteSites = function (index) {
      //var ID;
      //ID=index.id;
      //if(ID==1){
        $scope.promise.sites.splice(index, 1);
      //}
      //$scope.promise.sites.splice(ID-2, 1);

      //console.log($scope.promise.sites.splice(ID-2, 1));
      //console.log(ID);
      /*console.log($scope.promise.sites);
      console.log($scope.promise.sites.splice(index, 1));*/

    }
    $scope.deleteGroup = function (index) {
      //var ID;
      //ID=index.id;
      //if(ID==1){
        $scope.promise.groups.splice(index, 1);
      //}
      //$scope.promise.sites.splice(ID-2, 1);

      //console.log($scope.promise.sites.splice(ID-2, 1));
      //console.log(ID);
      /*console.log($scope.promise.sites);
      console.log($scope.promise.sites.splice(index, 1));*/

    }
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.url="";
    $scope.color="";
    $scope.group=[];
    $scope.addSite= function(){

        $scope.promise.sites.push({siteName: $scope.name, url: $scope.url, color: $scope.color});

    //      id = 2001;
    //      console.log(id);
    //         siteName = $scope.name;
    //         console.log(siteName);
    //         url=$scope.url;
    //         console.log(url);
    //         color=$scope.color;
    //         console.log(color);
    //         group=$scope.group;
    //         console.log(group);
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.url="";
    $scope.color="";
    $scope.group=[];
     };

});
```

JSON is huge, because I have 2000 sites and 50 groups.So I will just post few objcets

data.json

```
{
  "sites":[
          {
                "id": 1,
                "siteName":"Google",
                "url": "www.google.com",
                "color": "green",
                "group": ["Social","Sport","Games","News","Programming"]
          },

          {
                "id": 2,
                "siteName":"Facebook",
                "url": "www.facebook.com",
                "color": "blue",
                "group": []
          },

          {
                "id": 3,
                "siteName":"B92",
                "url": "www.b92.net",
                "color": "red",
                "group": ["Social","Sport"]
          },

          {
                "id": 4,
                "siteName":"9GAG",
                "url": "www.9gag.com",
                "color": "purple",
                "group": []
          }
],

  "groups":[
        {
                "id":1,
                "name":"Search Engine",
                "color":"green",
                "sites":["Google","Yahoo","Bing"]
        },
        {
                "id":2,
                "name":"Social",
                "color":"red",
                "sites":[]
        },
        {
                "id":3,
                "name":"Games",
                "color":"blue",
                "sites":[]
        },
        {
                "id":4,
                "name":"Informations",
                "color":"red",
                "sites":[]

        },
        {
                "id":5,
                "name":"Sport",
                "color":"orange",
                "sites":[]
        },
        {
                "id":6,
                "name":"Television",
                "color":"green",
                "sites":[]
        }
]
}
```

I have one fillter.

searchFilter.js

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){
  return function(arr, searchString){
    if(!searchString){
      return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item){

      if(item.siteName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1 && item.group.length!=0){
      result.push(item);
    }
    });
    return result;
  };
});
```

And of of course modal

modal.js

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      //controller:'siteCtrl',
      replace:true,
      scope: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

style.css

```
.container{
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
.container2 {
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 89.5px;
    margin-left: 89.5px;
}
img{
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
}
.btnDiv{
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

.sites-info{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
.btn .btn-primary{
    background:#000;
    color: white;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:700;
    border: none;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.siteForm{
    margin: 10% 15% 0 0;
    padding-left:50px;
}
.close-table{
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

li{
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
}
li hr{
    margin:0;
}

#table1{
    display:none;
}
.navbar-form , .justify{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.input-group{
    width: 600px;
}
.sites{
    display:inline;
     padding-right: 20px;
     line-height: 1.5em;
}
#sites{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: 350px;

}
.goToTop
    {
        display:none;
        background-color:#286090;
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 100000;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 10px;
        -moz-opacity: 0.60;
        opacity: .85;
        filter: alpha(opacity=85);
    }
```

I hope that I asked question correctly, thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your json. Did you try it with less data and less code?

Comment: No I haven't, my $scope can't recognize data from modal,when I put form in normal window , not in modal, $scope can recognize data.